# Test Authorize Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, test-first

i saw practice in TDD Book for Test Authorize Controller but i don't understand exactly what that means this is code

```
Assert.IsTrue(typeof (TodoController)
                  .GetCustomAttributes(true).ToList()
                  .Any(o=>o.GetType()==typeof(AuthorizeAttribute))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

They are checking that an `[Authorize]` attribute has been added to the `TodoController`. Note that they are not actually testing if the authorisation mechanism *works*, just that the `AuthorizeAttribute` decoration exists.

Answer (score 0):

It checks whether the `TodoController` has an `AuthorizeAttribute`, i.e. is decorated with `[Authorize]`

```
[Authorize] // <-- if this is present the test will pass, if not it will fail.
public class TodoController {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: tnx.what is the GetCustomAttributes(true) exactly

Comment: It returns an array of all custom attributes applied to the type. The agrgument should be set to `true` to search this member's inheritance chain to find the attributes, otherwise to `false`. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx